# A PDE is invariant under the Lie point symmetries

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lie-groups, symmetry

I am reading a paper: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/oca.2190

For the PDE (6) in that paper: 
$$V_t + V_{x_1}f_1(x_1,x_2)+V_{x_2}f_2(x_1,x_2)+Q(x_1,x_2)-\frac{b^2}{4r}V^2_{x_2}=0.$$

The paper says that it is invariant under the following Lie point symmetries:

1. Translation of time $\tilde{t} = t+s$ with group infinitesimal generator $\frac{\partial}{\partial_t}$.
2. Translation of the value function $\tilde{V} = V+s$ with group infinitesimal generator $\frac{\partial}{\partial V}$.

I really have no idea what this means and how to see this.

Moreover, it says,

> the meaning of two symmetries is that there always exists a solution of that PDE that does not depend on time.

Why?

Also are these symmetries helpful in any sense?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a sense, invariant means _unchanged_. If $t\to t+s$ with $s$ a number, then $V(x_{1},x_{2},t)\to V(x_{1},x_{2},t+s)$. Taking a partial derivative with respect to $t$ $$V_{t}(x_{1},x_{2},t)\to V_{t}(x_{1},x_{2},t+s)\cdot 1=V_{t}(x_{1},x_{2},t+s)$$ so the time derivative remains unchanged by a translation in $s$. Similarly, $V\to V+s$, then computing the derivative with respect to $i=x_{1},x_{2},t$, $$\partial_{i}V\to \partial_{i}V+\partial_{i}s=\partial_{i}V$$ Because the PDE is entirely derivatives, we see that the PDE remains unchanged so the solution is unchanged by a translation in $s$.